# Script assets:install returned with error code 255 - Shopware 6.5 Update

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

While updating from Shopware 6.4 to 6.5, I added symfony/flex to composer.json.
Running `composer update --with-all-dependencies --no-scripts` works, but `composer update --with-all-dependencies` does not. It returns the following Error:

```
Executing script assets:install [KO]
 [KO]
Script assets:install returned with error code 255
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle" not found in /home/mws/Dokumente/projekte/academy.rotkaeppchen-mumm.de/vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php:97
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 /home/mws/Dokumente/projekte/academy.rotkaeppchen-mumm.de/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(331): Shopware\Core\Kernel->registerBundles()
!!  #1 /home/mws/Dokumente/projekte/academy.rotkaeppchen-mumm.de/vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php(163): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
!!  #2 /home/mws/Dokumente/projekte/academy.rotkaeppchen-mumm.de/bin/console(74): Shopware\Core\Kernel->boot()
!!  #3 {main}
!!    thrown in /home/mws/Dokumente/projekte/academy.rotkaeppchen-mumm.de/vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php on line 97
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

What causes this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sensio/framework-extra-bundle` [has been removed as a dependency](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/changelog/release-6-5-0-0/2023-01-11-remove-sensio-framework-extra-bundle.md). If you followed the [migration to flex template instructions](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/template#how-do-i-migrate-from-production-template-to-symfony-flex) this shouldn't have been necessary, but you should be able to safely remove it from the `composer.json` and `config/bundles.php` if it still appears in either or both.